# Time of "go/come"

Tags: time-reference

Let's say it took David two days to travel from London to New York; he left on Friday and arrived on Sunday.

> 1. David went to New York on Friday.
> 2. David went to New York on Sunday.
> 3. David came to New York on Friday.
> 4. David came to New York on Sunday.

Which ones are correct?

Comment: CHECK : David "left for" New York on Friday & "arrived" [there] on Sunday. Alternatively , "started for" & "reached". Variations are there

Comment: (4) would probably be understood to mean _arrived in NY_, but the others are ambiguous if the journey took two days.

Comment: @KateBunting  Actually, what I wanted to ask about was,  for example, when the verb "to come" is used,  whether I should mark it with the starting point or the ending point of the 2-day time frame.

Comment: The end point - that's why I said it would be understood as _arrived_.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about which day to use with which verb:

> David went to New York on Friday

> David came to New York on Sunday

The others are wrong.

"Went" is talking about the departure. "Came" is talking about the arrival.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where YOU are.

If you are in New York, you'd say that David 'came' to you; otherwise, they 'went' somewhere else. Both of these would refer to his outward journey, but because of the speaker's perspective, you would probably say they 'came' on their arrival date but 'went' on their departure date.

Comment: Thank you. My priority concern is that  when the verb "to go "or "to come" is used, whether I should relate it to **Friday or Sunday** , in the given situation.